# Olive oil in glass bottle question?

Tags: oil

I have bought some olive oils glass bottles.

My question is - can I buy olive oil from the shop and add it to the bottle and add in some decoration like chillies, herbs etc? Or is there a process for decoration?

Thanks

Comment: Potential duplicates: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/75479/appropriate-oil-to-infuse-with-hot-chillies?rq=1 https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29673/infusing-olive-oil-with-herbs?rq=1 Summary: You need to take precautions to prevent botulism from growing in the infused oils.

Comment: Agree with @Johanna, but also, if this is for use beyond decoration, olive oil should be stored in dark glass only, as the monounsaturated acids are highly unstable.   Light will spoil your olive oil rather quickly.